# Streaming from Apple TV to MacBook

Tags: streaming

Can I stream to my computer to watch Netflix? Or, can I only stream from devices to computers? Seems quite limited, if so.

Comment: Ummm. Netflix has a web app...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch Netflix on your Mac, the best way to go is just use [Netflix.com](http://www.netflix.com/) (you'll need the [Silverlight plugin](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx)).

AppleTV doesn't have any capabilities to *send* streams (ala AirPlay), just receive them from other devices. The reason for this is effectively that the Apple TV doesn't really hold any content. It sources it all from other places, all of which can be accessed from your Mac (i.e. iTunes, Netflix, Hulu, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In your favorite browser, go to the [Netflix Watch Instantly page](http://movies.netflix.com/WiHome), sign in, and enjoy.

Its just that simple!